# bootstrap double datepicker value parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a form with 2 field that contains bootstrap datepicker. And I wanna set the startDate Of second field with the value from first field. can you 
help me?? Here is my sample html code

```html
 <title>Pusat Penelitian Bioteknologi LIPI</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/img/logolipi.png" type="image/x-icon">
 <link href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/js/notifikasi.js"></script>
 <script src="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <link href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!--header-->
<!--header-->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color:#7AD0E7;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/beranda_user"><img src="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/assets/img/logolipikecil.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li >
    <a href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/beranda_user"><font color="white">
     <b>BERANDA</b></font>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="active">
    <a href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/barang_user"><font color="white">
     <b>BARANG</b></font>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li >
    <a href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/informasi_user"><font color="white">
     <b>INFORMASI</b></font>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li >
    <a href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/riwayat"><font color="white">
     <b>RIWAYAT</b></font>
    </a>
   </li>
    </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="dropdown" >
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><font color="white"><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;tutang</b>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></font></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/beranda_admin">MENU ADMIN</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/profil">PROFIL</a></li>
     <li class="divider"></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/masuk/keluar">LOGOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container -->
</div><!--/.navbar -->

<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color:#f5f5f5">
 <h5 style="margin-left:1150px">24-Mar-2015</h5>
</div>
<!--judul-->
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:5px;">
  <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:#f1f1f2">
    <h3 style="margin-left:115px;"><a href="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/barang_user">DAFTAR BARANG</a> / FORMULIR PEMINJAMAN</h3>
  </div>
</div>


<!--body-->

<div class="container" style="background-color:#F1F1F2; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;" >
    <div class="panel-body">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="form_pinjam" name="form_pinjam" action="http://localhost/SIPEKAT/barang_user/simpan">
   <div class="form-header" style="background-color:#7AD0E7;">
    <font color="white"><center>INFORMASI BARANG<center></font>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="nama_barang" class="col-md-3 control-label">Nama Barang</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama_barang" name="nama_barang" placeholder="Nama Barang" value="Thermohygrometer / Alat Ukur " disabled>
     <input type="hidden" name="nama_barang_tmp" id="nama_barang_tmp" value="Thermohygrometer / Alat Ukur ">
     <input type="hidden" name="kd_barang" id="kd_barang" value="3030301086">
     <input type="hidden" name="nip" id="nip" value="196304231988031002">
    </div><br />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Pilih Aset</label>
     <div class="col-md-8">
      <table class="table">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th><center>Kode Aset</center></th>
         <th><center>Kondisi</center></th>
         <th><center>Status</center></th>
         <th><center>Keterangan</center></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>
           <div class="checkbox" >
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="aset[]"value="3030301086-001"></label>
           </div>
          </td>
          <td><center>3030301086-001</center></td>
           <input type="hidden" id="kondisi_3030301086-001" value="baik">
           <input type="hidden" id="status_3030301086-001" value="baik">
          <td><center>baik</center></td>
          <td><center>baik</center></td>
          <td><center>-</center></td>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-header" style="background-color:#7AD0E7;">
    <font color="white"><center>INFORMASI LAINNYA<center></font>
   </div><br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="keperluan" class="col-md-3 control-label">Keperluan</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <textarea class="form-control" name="keperluan" id="keperluan" placeholder="Keperluan"></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tanggal_pinjam" class="col-md-3 control-label">Tanggal pinjam</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tanggal_pinjam" id="tanggal_pinjam" placeholder="Tanggal pinjam" >
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tanggal_kembali" class="col-md-3 control-label">Tanggal Kembali</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tanggal_kembali" id="tanggal_kembali"  placeholder="Tanggal Kembali">
    </div>
   </div> 
   <div style="margin-left:900px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" form="form_pinjam" id="kirim">Kirim</button>
   </div>
  </form>  
 </div>
</div>
</div>``
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
  
  $('#tabel').dataTable();
  
 var date = new Date();
 date.setDate(date.getDate()); //disini tempat buat ganti hari mulainya datepicker
 
 
 $('#tanggal_pinjam').datepicker({
 format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
 weekStart: 1,
 startDate: date,
 clearBtn: true,
 language: "id",
 keyboardNavigation: false,
 forceParse: false,
 daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
 todayHighlight: true,
 
 });
 
 $('#tanggal_kembali').datepicker({
 
 format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
 weekStart: 1,
 clearBtn: true,
 language: "id",
 startDate: date ,
 keyboardNavigation: false,
 forceParse: false,
 daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
 todayHighlight: true
   
 });
 
    });
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

Below is the js code: http://jsfiddle.net/rgej2z2e/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dt').datepicker({minDate:0});
    $('#startDate').on('change', function(e){
        $('#endDate').datepicker('update', $(this).val());
    });
});
```

I hope it's help :)

Comment: @febyana-chinta-utami is it wroking for you?